# fast preprocessing with OpenCV as an input for tesseract OCR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract, opencv3.0

I have been lately playing around with tesseract-ocr, for scanning receipts.

I managed to retrieve some of the words and numbers but for some reason few numbers are left out :/ .

The given image to tesseract was converted into Black and white, and after manual changes I managed to find out the small space around each line is one of the reasons for the the actual numbers got discarded, my assumption is maybe those lines with words make it difficult to tesseract to retrieve the numbers in the row below (**the rows are quite close to each other although there is a white space between them**)

tesseract's configuration is:

```
  --psm 4 --oem 0
```

Is someone familiar with this, is line space truly effects tesseract ocr results?

if so i guess i'll need to:
iterate over all lines and then iterate over blobs which belong to the same line and shift them vertically for increasing the space (sounds a bit tedious). don't you think?

Comment: It is hard to tell whats wrong without seeing preprocessed image, but you don't need to shift anything, just extract the line ROI from the image and pass it to the tesseract line-by-line. That way you will also be able to deskew folded receipts.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriiZ, i'll look into it!